# how to circumvent a filter a txt document with pandas where a row has string, int and floats

Tags: python, pandas, string, filter

I have a format for a txt file like this:

```
  501NA      NA    1   9.517   6.338   0.776
  502NA      NA    2   2.683   7.229   0.642
  503NA      NA    3   6.856   9.313   0.543
  504NA      NA    4   9.412   3.246   0.808
  505NA      NA    5   1.994   2.141   0.620
  506NA      NA    6   3.571   9.574   0.575
```

I've got pandas to read the txt file, which I am most happy about. But when I try to filter it based on a condition it says it can't. I want pandas to spit out the data in the exact looking format it came in...basically output it as a txt string.

here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("blockbig2.gro",sep= "\s+", header= None, keep_default_na=False)
data.columns = ['id', 'NA','index','x' ,'y','z']
print(data)

equation_x = ((data.x)-5)**2
equation_y = ((data.y)-5)**2
eq = equation_x + equation_y
data[eq<=24].to_txt('step1.txt',float_format = "%.3f", index = False ,header = False )
```

the print command gives me the right format, which I like. But what part am I missing?

Comment: what is the error message or your output, and your desired output?

Comment: Where did you find the `to_txt` method? That does not exist and I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_txt'`

Comment: this is my error:                                                                   
 result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'                            if you can't use to_txt, how can pandas make a .txt document?